# how to run liquibase from commandline AND see the statetement logging?

Tags: liquibase

We had version 3.4.1, which worked OK. Some of our team members are used to invoking liquibase from commandline, and want to see statements being invoked. After upgrading to 3.6.3 this feature was broken, I've seen several posts, which tried to provide info how to bring this liquibase feature back to action, however none of them did not work for us, and no logging is produced. I've tried to upgrade to newest version 3.7.0 and 3.8.0 but situation with them are even worse, as these version fails with NPE etc., does not work at all, and I can see unclosed related tickets to that.

(no offense now) What is the last release, which can be considered as working (regarding execution from cmdline and maven) and which can be configured so that statements will be printed?

Documentation for cmd-line execution shows:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
      --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=website.war \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      update
```

we're using the very same command, but also with parameters:

```
--logLevel=INFO --defaultSchemaName="abc"  --contexts="abc"
```

but that shouldn't do any harm. What needs to be done with this, so that logging will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known issues in logging in those versions. Not very well documented in the Liquibase jira database, but well known to the team. We are currently (10/24/2019) working on a 3.8.1 release that should fix the issues we know about.

Comment: If solution will require some special invocation, can you please update the documentation when 3.8.1 is out? Thanks!

Comment: Will do - the plan is to have it work as it used to. We are moving to a new logging framework (slf4j will be the new native logging framework) but the hope is that the CLI will still work as it used to. Some changes came in in the 3.6.x line that are just now being addressed. Datical is starting to put more resources on Liquibase.